# In what a case won't this function return a value? Why does the compiler report an error?

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, return

```
public static int Test(int n)
{
  if (n < 0) return 1;
  if (n == 0) return 2;
  if (n > 0) return 3;
}
```

Compiler (Visual Studio 2010, C# 4.0) says "Not all code paths return a value". Why?

Comment: Hi, I edited your post to show all the code. In StackOverflow, you just need to either 1. indent any code with four spaces, or 2. Highlight your code when you're done and click the `{}` button. (Your code was caught up by the `<` and `>` characters, I think.)

Comment: why the operator between n and 0 is missing?

Comment: Why bother with the last comparison (n>0)?  It's obviously going to be > 0 if it gets to that point, so skip the redundant comparison and just return 3 if you get to that point.

Comment: Also, I suppose you could theoretically change the value of 'n' during the function, and even though you don't, the compiler can't guarantee that?...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler isn't looking at your conditions. Even though you are correct that at least one of your if-blocks will run, you still need to refactor to something like this:

```
if (n < 0)
    return 1;
else if (n == 0)
    return 2;
else
    return 3;
```

Answer (score 10):

The compiler doesn't try to determine that this covers all the possible values of `n`. All it sees is that you have three `if` statements, and it assumes that it's possible for *all* of them to be false... in which case you'd reach the end of the method without returning a value.

See [this blog post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx) for more details about the compiler's limits when it comes to reachability.

Just make the final return unconditional.

Comment: Jon Skeet -> Eric Lippert -> Alan Turning -> Halting problem

Answer (score 2):

The compiler isn't smart enough to know that all of those branches are mutually exclusive, so it worries about the fallthrough case where all three if statements fail.

You can either link all the `if` statements with `else` and use only `else` for the last condition, or you can return a default value at the end. This will get around the issue.

Comment: It has even been proved that it never can be smart enough. It's called the Halting problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @Jonas Elfström: Very true. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know you've covered all your bases.  You can rewrite it like this...

```
public static int Test(int n)
{
  if (n < 0) return 1;
  else if (n == 0) return 2;
  else (n > 0) return 3;
}
```

or this...

```
public static int Test(int n)
{
  if (n < 0) return 1;
  if (n == 0) return 2;
  if (n > 0) return 3;
  return 4; //will never occur
}
```